# インテルプロセッサーからメモリー初期化したい

Tags: memory

インテルプロセッサーからメモリー初期化したいけど仕様書が無いです。
どこにありますか？

https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/ijkk/jp/ja/documents/developer/IA32_Arh_Dev_Man_Vol3_i.pdf#page=363

IBMはあったのですが。

Answer (score 2):

こちらにあるものではありませんか？
この辺の資料・記事やそれらに示されている紹介資料を調べてみてはどうでしょう？

[Minimum Steps Necessary to Boot an Intel® Architecture Platform](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/intelligent-systems/intel-boot-loader-development-kit/minimal-intel-architecture-boot-loader-paper.html)
[Minimal Intel Architecture Boot Loader](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/minimal-intel-architecture-boot-loader-paper.pdf)
ちょっと表記はズレますが、目次にこんなものが示されています。

> - Preparation for Memory Initialization ........................................................ 8
>
>   - Processor Microcode Update .......................................................... 8
>   - Processor Initialization .................................................................. 8
>   - Chipset Initialization ..................................................................... 9
> - Memory Initialization .............................................................................. 9
>
>   - Technical Resources ..................................................................... 9
>   - MRC Dependencies ..................................................................... 10
> - Post Memory Initialization ..................................................................... 10
>
>   - Memory Test ............................................................................. 11
>   - Firmware Shadow ...................................................................... 11
>   - Memory Transaction Re-Direction ................................................. 11
>   - Stack Setup .............................................................................. 12
>   - Transfer to DRAM ....................................................................... 12

それからStackOverflowの記事にこんなものがあります。
もしかしたら、あなたの疑問の大本に近いかもしれません。
[How Does BIOS initialize DRAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63159663/9014308)

その回答の中に該当資料は *BIOS Writer Guide* と呼ばれ機密情報であり漏洩していないとあります。

> The document you (and also I) are looking for is called the *BIOS Writer Guide* and, unfortunately, is confidential and has not leaked so far (AFAIK).

ただし続けてFirmware Support Packageというのがリリースされていて、そこに解説と(バイナリ)コードも含まれていると書かれています。
オープンソース開発者やNDA(機密保持契約)を結ぶ余裕のない開発者はそれを使えるでしょうとあるので、関連する情報が書かれているのではないですか？

> In order to promote their product in the Open Source community, Intel released the [Firmware Support Package](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-firmware-support-package.html). This is to be considered akin to a library for the firmware writers and contains (binary) code to initialize the memory controller, the PCH (Peripheral Controller Hub, informally known as "the chipset"), and the CPU1.
> An open source developer, or in general any developer that cannot afford to sign an NDA with Intel, can use the FSP to writes their own firmware.

回答には続けて詳細な内容が記述されているので、それだけでもある程度知りたいことが分かるかもしれません。

Comment: わざわざ親切に有難うです。